# How to overwrite ClaimIdentity from HttpRequestData.Identities while working with isolated azure function

Tags: .net-7.0, executioncontext, principalcontext, azure-functions-isolated

I'm working with .net 7 isolated azure function. before processing the business I need to add more information to the Claim Identity like the code below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PreprocessingRequestAsync(**HttpRequestData request**, Func<Task<IActionResult>> logic)
        {
            var hasId = request.Headers.TryGetValues("id", out var id);
            var hasUsername = request.Headers.TryGetValues("username", out var username);
            var hasEmail = request.Headers.TryGetValues("email", out var email);

            if (hasId &&
                hasUsername &&
                hasEmail)
            {
                var user = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                    {
                        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
                            id.FirstOrDefault()),
                        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname",
                            username.FirstOrDefault()),
                        new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
                            email.FirstOrDefault())
                    }
                    , "ByPassAuth");

                **request.Identities.Append(user);**

                var response = await ContinueToProcessBusinessLogicAsync(logic, request, false);
                return response;
            }
        }
```

The above code was not able to work as expected (add more information to the Claim Identity).
I know that Identities is ready-only property, but is there any way that allow me to do that.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your own Middleware that would push data to the `FunctionContext`.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Middleware;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureFunctionApp.Middleware
{
    public class TokenMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly string _issuer = "https://accounts.google.com";
        private readonly string _audience = "$(GoogleClientID)";
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            var request = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();
            var token = request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization").FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();

            if (token != null)
            {
                ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = await ValidateAndExtractClaimsAsync(token);

                if (claimsPrincipal != null)
                {
                    context.Items.Add("User", claimsPrincipal); // <-- this is where you're saving data
                }
            }

            await next(context);
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> ValidateAndExtractClaimsAsync(string jwtToken)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var discoveryDocument = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(_issuer + "/.well-known/openid-configuration");
            var jwksUri = JsonDocument.Parse(discoveryDocument).RootElement.GetProperty("jwks_uri").GetString();
            var jwksResponse = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(jwksUri);
            var jwks = JsonDocument.Parse(jwksResponse).RootElement;

            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = _issuer,
                ValidAudience = _audience,
                IssuerSigningKeys = ExtractSigningKeys(jwks),
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
            };

            try
            {
                ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParameters, out _);
                return claimsPrincipal;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null; // Token validation failed
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<SecurityKey> ExtractSigningKeys(JsonElement jwks)
        {
            var keys = jwks.GetProperty("keys").EnumerateArray();
            var signingKeys = new List<SecurityKey>();

            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                var keyType = key.GetProperty("kty").GetString();
                var modulusBase64Url = key.GetProperty("n").GetString();
                var exponentBase64Url = key.GetProperty("e").GetString();

                var modulusBytes = Base64UrlDecode(modulusBase64Url);
                var exponentBytes = Base64UrlDecode(exponentBase64Url);

                var keyParameters = new RSAParameters
                {
                    Modulus = modulusBytes,
                    Exponent = exponentBytes,
                };

                var rsa = RSA.Create();
                rsa.ImportParameters(keyParameters);
                signingKeys.Add(new RsaSecurityKey(rsa));
            }

            return signingKeys;
        }

        private byte[] Base64UrlDecode(string input)
        {
            string base64 = input.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
            while (base64.Length % 4 != 0)
            {
                base64 += "=";
            }
            return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        }
    }
}
```

Now use your middleware in the `Program.cs`:

```cs
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
    {
        builder.UseMiddleware<TokenMiddleware>();
    })
```

And now access the `User` object in the Function:

```cs
[Function("FunctionName")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext functionContext)
{
   var identity = functionContext.Items["User"] as ClaimsPrincipal;
   var name = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

  // the rest of the function code
}
```